# Como popular um <select> dinâmicamente?

Tags: php, html-select, codeigniter-3

Estou tentando criar um `<select>`, **onde ao selecionar** o `estado`, o **mesmo exibe as** `cidades` **noutro campo**. Os `estados` **estão chegando até o meu** `controller`, porém **não é exibido no campo** do `<select>`.

Ou seja, no `<select name="estado">` os mesmos **não são retornados**, mas se eu utilizar o `var_dump` no `options_estados` no `controller`, os mesmos **são retornados**.

**Qual a minha dificuldade?**

- a) Descobrir qual problema está ocorrendo.
- b) Exibir os dados no meu campo dentro da minha `view`.

**MEU CONTROLLER**

```
public function create() {
    $variaveis['titulo'] = 'Novo Cadastro';
    $this->load->model("m_estados_cidades");
    $estados = $this->m_estados_cidades->retorna_estados();

    $option = "<option value=''></option>";
    foreach($estados -> result() as $linha) {
        $option .= "<option value='$linha->id'>$linha->nome</option>"; 
    }

    $variaveis['options_estados'] = $option;
    $this->load->view('v_cadastro', $variaveis); 
}
```

**MINHA VIEW**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="estado">Estado</label>
     <select id="estado" name="estado" class="form-control">
         <?php echo $options_estados; ?>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: ja tentaste `<option value='{$linha->id}'>{$linha->nome}</option>` ?

Comment: Já tentei e continua do mesmo jeito, não vem os estados.